# React State Hook - toggle a class

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a sidebar navigation menu and thought I'd take advantage of the new State hook in React. I've read the docs but can't seem to find an example similar to what I need, which is quite simply to toggle a CSS class on click which will in turn open and close my menu.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
const SidebarMenuItem = ({ component }) => {
  const [ menuActive, setMenuState ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li className="p-sidebar-menu-item">
      menuActive:
      { menuActive }
      <button className="p-sidebar-menu-item__link" onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuActive)}>{ component.component }</button>
      { component.children && (
        <ul className="p-sidebar-menu">
          <li><a href={`/${component.slug}`}>Overview</a></li>
          { component.children.map((subPage, key) => (
            <li key={ key }>
              <a href={`/${subPage.slug}`}>{ subPage.name }</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  )
}

export default SidebarMenuItem;
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: where you are using `menuActive` to change/toggle the element/css in your code, i can't see in code, you have shown. Created a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/km04on9l25), `menuActive` getting updated properly check once.

Comment: `CSS class on click which will in turn open and close my menu.` How is this working? Where you should put the class to open and close? What class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just make the className dynamic, so instead of setting

```
<li className="p-sidebar-menu-item">
```

transform it in a template literal

```
<li className={`p-sidebar-menu-item`}>
```

and then add your class conditionally (the "yellow" class in my example)

```
<li className={`p-sidebar-menu-item ${menuActive ? "yellow" : ""}`}>
```

Take a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv3qnlx347?fontsize=14): here I've just added your component and changed the way the `className` attribute is generated.

If you want to avoid the ternary operator you could use the [classnames module](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and then update your code to

```
import c from "classnames";
...
...
...
<li className={c("p-sidebar-menu-item", {yellow: menuActive})}>
```

Another clean solution can be to generate the className string in advance, for example

```
let classes = "p-sidebar-menu-item";
if(menuActive) {
  classes += " yellow";
}
<li className={classes}>
```

Let me know if you need some more help

Comment: Thanks very much. This did the trick. I'm fine with using the ternary operator. I think my main issue was I wasn't correctly logging the value of the state to the screen so assumed something else in my code was wrong. Once I JSON stringified it as you suggested the value popped up and then I just had to use the variable.

Comment: Yep, I guessed that you was stuck because of the wrong log  remember that a boolean isn't rendered by React 

Comment: @NoriSte how can you change `{classes}` after generating the string on a ajax callback?

Comment: You can store it with `React.useState`, and updating it after the AJAX call. Then, every time you set an internal state, the component is re-rendered and so the classes updated 

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use the prevState or you can have a bug.

```js
<button
  className="p-sidebar-menu-item__link"
  onClick={() => setMenuState((prevMenuActive) => !prevMenuActive)}>
{component.component}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
const [ menuActive, setMenuState ] = useState(false);
```

change the name of setState to setMenuState in your code also

Comment: I've updated my code snippet in the question as per your suggestions but its still not right. Is this how you meant?